# Find nodes with same related nodes in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j, cypher

I have a database containing scientific papers and the corresponding authors in the following schema:

```
(a:Author {id:1})-[:WROTE]->(p:Paper {title:"XY"})<-[:WROTE]-(b:Author {id:2})
```

I want to find authors that often wrote on papers together.

I started querying a list of authors with their "collaboration count" by:

```
MATCH (a:Author)-[:WROTE]->(p:Paper)<-[:WROTE]-(b:Author)
WITH a, b, COUNT(p) AS count
ORDER BY count DESC
RETURN a.name, b.name, count
LIMIT 10
```

This results in:

`| a.name   | b.name   | count |
|----------|----------|-------|
| Author A | Author B | 10    |
| Author B | Author A | 10    |
| Author C | Author D | 4     |
| Auhtor D | Author C | 4     |
| ...      | ...      | ...   |`

Is there a way to remove duplicates?

And is there a possibility to show a graph which contains the authors with the related papers they wrote together?

**EDIT:** I used the following query, but i'm not quite sure if it's returning the wished result:

```
MATCH (a:Author)-[:WROTE]->(p:Paper)<-[:WROTE]-(b:Author)
WITH a, b, collect(p) AS paper, COUNT(p) AS count
ORDER BY count DESC
LIMIT 10
RETURN a, b, paper
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove duplicates you can add an `WHERE` clause like the following:

```
MATCH (a:Author)-[:WROTE]->(p:Paper)<-[:WROTE]-(b:Author)
WHERE id(a) > id(b)
WITH a, b, COUNT(p) AS count
ORDER BY count DESC
RETURN a.name, b.name, count
LIMIT 10
```